# The Material class in my new project doesn't know the home and route properties

Tags: flutter, android-studio, material-components-android

I have just created a new flutter project and when i try to define the 'home' property in the Material app i get the following error: 'the parameter 'home' isn't defined.'

What could have something to do with it, is that i just updated my sdk to:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

After that i changed it back to:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

When i open the Material class, i see that there are no properties in the class related to routing.

This is my main.dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(home: );
  }
}
 and this is the code
```

of the Material class (which i didn't change, but this is how it came when created):

```
const Material({
    Key? key,
    this.type = MaterialType.canvas,
    this.elevation = 0.0,
    this.color,
    this.shadowColor,
    this.textStyle,
    this.borderRadius,
    this.shape,
    this.borderOnForeground = true,
    this.clipBehavior = Clip.none,
    this.animationDuration = kThemeChangeDuration,
    this.child,
  }) : assert(type != null),
       assert(elevation != null && elevation >= 0.0),
       assert(!(shape != null && borderRadius != null)),
       assert(animationDuration != null),
       assert(!(identical(type, MaterialType.circle) && (borderRadius != null || shape != null))),
       assert(borderOnForeground != null),
       assert(clipBehavior != null),
       super(key: key);
```

As you can see there is no home or routes property anymore. When i open an old project, it does have these properties.

Anyone have an idea what happened?

Comment: Add your `MaterialApp` code to the question

Answer (score 1):

Ah this was so silly. Thank you @ Sajad Abdollahi, I see the name of the class should be MaterialApp instead of Material. I have been using an outdated course on Flutter so I think this is where I went wrong.